# How to use React's built-in React.memo comparison function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to check whether a certain prop changed manually, then use React's built-in comparison function for the other props. E.g.:

```
React.memo(
  () => <div />,
  (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    if (!nextProps.visible) {
      return true;
    }
    return React.shallowCompare(prevProps, nextProps);
  },
);
```

I can easily write my own comparison function or copy/paste from React's source, but if React changes their default comparison function then I'd have to manually change my function too. Is there a way to use React's built-in comparison function for `React.memo`?

Also, AFAIK, `react-addons-shallow-compare` is outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. React defaults to `shallowEqual` in the event you don't provide a compare function, but there isn't additional logic for using the default behavior if you return anything special (e.g. `return null`).

[React's usage](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberBeginWork.new.js#L466):

```
const prevProps = currentChild.memoizedProps;
// Default to shallow comparison
let compare = Component.compare;
compare = compare !== null ? compare : shallowEqual;
if (compare(prevProps, nextProps) && current.ref === workInProgress.ref) {
...
```

React isn't currently exporting `shallowEqual`. However, [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) states that it only shallow compares, which is unlikely to change much and can be trivially implemented as you know ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22266891/724591)). I'm assuming this decision is to reduce the API their team exposes to developers.

Comment: For reference, React's [`shallowCompare` is here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/shared/shallowEqual.js); you'll need to copy in their `Object.is` and `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`. I've made [a gist](https://gist.github.com/elyobo/934f6896788236670ec4367c89a79412), stripping flow types (and reformatting slightly to my own preferences) if that's easier.

Comment: [This GH issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16919) (closed) requests that the `shallowCompare` be exported, but it was closed with very little discussion. Please add your thoughts there if you'd find this useful.